# Limits breaks and spell force

Tags: shadowrun-sr5

After reading through spellcasting I'm a bit unsure as to how **F** is handled effectively in regards to limit breaks via edge.

When I have the *focused concentration* quality (p. 74) at rating 2 or a *sustaining fokus* (p. 320) with a force of 2 is it then possible to just cast a spell at force 2, use edge to *Push the Limit* (p. 56) and then in effect get 10 successes and thus effectively an **F** 10 spell which can still be sustained by a force 2 focus or with the *focused concentration* quality of rating 2?

Answer (score 1):

**Yes.**

You're right that you can use Edge to break the Force Limit with spells, and that doing so has a pretty positive synergy with sustaining spell foci and the Increased Concentration quality (in the English version, this quality is called Focused Concentration), since it can make a spell quite a bit more powerful and still maintain it cheaply.

One drawback is that the Force is still low, so for many spells that rely on the Force for effect (like Indirect Combat Spells use the Force for damage) will be weaker cast this way.  But it's great for spells that only use the hits for effect (like Direct Combat Spells).

*But be careful.*  Because the spell's Limit is removed and you're adding bonus dice from Edge to it, it is much easier to roll more hits than your Magic attribute and convert the Drain from Stun to Physical.  There will be less Drain than usual since you're using a lower Force, but the Drain you take could matter quite a bit more since a few minutes' rest won't remove it.

*One more thing...*  Rather than Edge, you can also use reagents to *change* a spell's Limit to make it different than its force.  There's two very good uses for doing so, although I'm sure a creative player will come up with more.  The obvious use is to use a low Force and a lot of reagents to set the Limit high without getting a lot of Drain, like we've already talked about.  But unlike Edge, reagents will work *the other way around* too, allowing you to set a high Force but reduce the maximum hits to ensure you don't suffer Physical Drain.  For example, if you're boosting a stat your friend already has a maxed, you'll never need more than four hits on an Increase (Attribute) spell.  But, if you're boosting an Elf's Charisma, you might need a Force of 12, which is a huge deal - and possibly fatal to the caster on a bad Drain Resistance roll.  Using reagents to limit your hits to four while still allowing the teammate's Charisma to go from 8 to 12 is probably a good idea.

(One of my magi used this on himself, playing as a Shinto mage, which uses Charisma to resist Drain, and the Quickening metamagic;  setting the Force to 16 made the quickened spell *very* difficult to disrupt, even in low magic zones, but he took enough Stun damage from the Drain that it would have killed him if it had been Physical [it rolled over into Physical, but not enough to kill him].)

Comment: Tnx for the answer but not sure about a thing there: As far as I understood the drain you have to take and roll against is the number of successes (not netto succs but total succs without taking the limit into account) and thus not reliant from the force of the spell?   Another thing: When I got asked myself about that thing which caused my question here was when a player mentioned a few spells like increase reaction where the number of succs are counted and not the force

Comment: @Thomas I will check again when I get home from work, I am pretty sure the Force sets amount of Drain but the number of hits sets the Type (Stun or Physical), so setting the Limit equal to or less than your Magic Attribute protects you from Physical Drain.

Comment: @ThomasE. SR5 Chapter **Magic** - Sorcery - Spellcasting - Step 4:  Cast Spell:  If the number of hits (not net hits) you get (**after applying the limit** or Edge spending) exceeds your Magic rating, the spell’s Drain is Physical instead of Stun damage.  (The reason it says *not net hits* is that some spells have Thresholds you need to hit, most notably Object Resistance, and those don't subtract from your hits to determine Drain severity.)